# How to convert the output of a performance counter to an int in c#

Tags: c#, performance, int, counter

I am having an error when i try to display the current CPU and memory usage using a progress bar. The code seems to be correct as it works with a label, but I am getting an error "Cannot convert to int" so how can I convert the performance counter's data into an int so it can be displayed in a progress bar? I tried using `System.Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter);` but it didn't work out for me. Here is my code:

```
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        ramCounter.NextValue();
        progressBar1.Value = ramCounter;

        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
        cpuCounter.NextValue();
        progressBar2.Value = cpuCounter;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the *result* of `PerformanceCounter.NextValue()` - you're currently ignoring it:

```
float value = cpuCounter.NextValue();
progressBar2.Value = (int) value;
```

You'll want to check the range of expected values of course - you may well want to scale it.

Another option is to use the [`RawValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.rawvalue.aspx) property, which is a `long`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. You are right, I do need to scale the output but I am clueless on how to do that :( Any ideas? :)

Comment: @Shadowalker: You'd need to give us more information - basically work out what you want your output range to be, what the input range is, and then multiply and add appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign the Performance Counter instance to your progress bar but its value. The value itself is Int64.

```
progressbar1.Value = (Int32) ramCounter.RawValue;
```

Yours,
  Alois Kraus